# How to change presentation of packages in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, package

I need to work with Eclipse source. And I have many packages imported:

```
org.eclipse.core
org.eclipse.jdt
org.eclipse.jdt.core
org.eclipse.core.resources
etc
```

So I have all this packages in my project. How can I divide them by their tree? So they look like this in my project:

```
org
  +
  |- eclipse + 
             |- core
             |     +
             |     |- runtime
             |     |- resources
             |- jdt
                  +
                  |- core
                        +
                        |- dom
```

Comment: Open `Package Explorer` and click on a button similar to `-><-`

Comment: @SrinivasThatiparthy: You should convert this into an answer

Comment: @SrinivasThatiparthy you were close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srinivas Thatiparthy's comment was close. There is an option "Package presentation" under another button that is next to the button similar to "-><-".